# CSS - Using :hover doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my HTML/CSS work so when I hover over a list item the other ul appears. The code I have doesn't seem to work.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz29tt6r/)

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.navbar>li, a:hover + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.dropdown-content` is not an adjacent sibling of any `a` element, its the great-grandfather's sibling.

Comment: I don't think it works like that.. you'll have to add the `:hover` on the `.nvbar` class since it is the one adjacent to the `'.dropdown-content`, the `li` is not.. you will have to use JS or JQuery to get this done using `.mouseover()` or `.hover()`